# Vue API Calls and Laravel Middleware

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, middleware

Is it possible to globally set a listener on API calls made with Axios in Vue? The Laravel back-end has middleware set up on each endpoint that will either give the requested data or return a message saying that they need to check their messages. My goal is to capture that message and redirect the user to the page to view their message. I can't think of a way to do this other than setting something on each function that checks for the message and responds accordingly. There are hundreds of functions and that it wouldn't be a clean solution.

Any and all recommendations are welcome!

Comment: I think what you might be looking for are [Axios Interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors).

Comment: @Bogdan That looks like its in the right vein of what I am looking for, thank you for sharing that. Would this have to be done on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: Interceptors are global methods called on every request/response. So if you have 100 request from various parts of your app, the interceptors will run for any of them regardless of their origin. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Thats exactly what I was asking. I'll look into the syntax  of it and try to set it up. The goal would be to detect a specific response from any of the endpoints, if that response is detected then I need to redirect the user to another page. That can be accomplished, correct? Also, please feel free to submit an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Axios Interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) you can do something along these lines:

```js
this.$http.interceptors.response.use(response => () {
    // Redirect to a new page when you send
    // custom header from the server
    if (response.headers.hasOwnProperty('my-custom-header')) {
        window.location.href = '/another-page';
    }

    // Or when you get a specific response status code
    if (response.status === 402) {
        window.location.href = '/another-page';
    }

    // Or when the response contains some specific data
    if (response.data.someKey === 'redirect') {
        window.location.href = '/another-page';
    }

    // ...or whatever you want
});
```

Comment: This worked like a dream, I ended up using the 2nd example to check for the response and confirm the exact message I was expecting, and used router.push to redirect the user to the appropriate page while retaining the message. Thank you, @Bogdan! I'd upvote but I don't have enough points yet :-)